# Compare Complex XML to a list of values in BPEL

Tags: xml, xslt, comparison, bpel

I am using Jdev 11g, BPEL 2.0 .A Service Retrieves all the ID's for one single customer and the output XML is as below, I have to compare all the ID's with a given set of numbers i.e 10,15,20,30 and set a condition that if any one of the Cust ID has these numbers then throw an exception.
Any ideas? I tried using string functions in Transform activity but in vain, and If activity conditions only compare the first value (10A) with the numbers list.
Any inputs would be great.

```
<env:Header>
</env:Header>
<env:Body>
<processResponse
<ns4:Result>
<ns5:CustId 
<ns3:CustRecrdList
<ns3:CustRecrd>
<ns3:CustRecrdID>10A</ns3:CustRecrdID>
</ns3:CustRecrd>
<ns3:CustRecrd>
<ns3:CustRecrdID>32D</ns3:CustRecrdID>
</ns3:CustRecrd>
<ns3:CustRecrd>
<ns3:CustRecrdID>55M</ns3:CustRecrdID>
</ns3:CustRecrd>
<ns3:CustRecrd>
<ns3:CustRecrdID>15C</ns3:CustRecrdID>
</ns3:CustRecrd>
<ns3:CustRecrd>
<ns3:CustRecrdID>10B</ns3:CustRecrdID>
</ns3:CustRecrd>
<ns3:CustRecrd>
<ns3:CustRecrdID>23F</ns3:CustRecrdID>
</ns3:CustRecrd>
<ns3:CustRecrd>
<ns3:CustRecrdID>20D</ns3:CustRecrdID>
</ns3:CustRecrd>
</ns3:CustRecrdList>
</ns5:CustId>
</ns4:Result>
</processResponse>
</env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Comment: `contains`? http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-contains

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the Oracle Forum Discussion where you've posted this same question:

https://forums.oracle.com/message/11047780#11047780

Regards,

Melvin

Ps. Don't forget to rate the answers ;)